# Saving input from modal to one of three different tables

Tags: javascript

I have 3 tables in a div that I want to make editable. At the bottom of each table there is an "add" button that opens a modal (they all open the same modal).  I have the following JS to add new rows:

How do I get the JS to know which of the three tables to add the row to? The three tables I have are acc_table1, acc_table2, acc_table3. I tried "var table = document.getElementById("acc_table"+no);" which did not work.

```
  if (tit.innerHTML === "Add Account"){
          var table = document.getElementById("acc_table1");
          var row = table.insertRow(0);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_type").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_price").value;
}
```

Comment: each table has a button to open the same modal. then on the button click save the table id in a variable then when you want to add the value to the table use that variable

Comment: I added a hidden variable that is updated when the modal is opened using `table = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;`  and `document.getElementById('table_num').value = table.getAttribute('id');` - does that seem correct?

Comment: I dont know. I dont have your html to know what is e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement however my answer down below does not require a hidden element. I can furthur explain my answer if you can not figure out how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to store desired table ID to use it when you want to save the data to table.

Something along like the example below

```js
var tableId = "";
function openModalFunction(selectedTableId){
  tableId = selectedTableId;
}
 
 
function saveDataToTable(){
  var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "cell 1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell 2";
 }
```

```html
<table id="acc_table1">
<thead><tr><th colspan=2>Table 1</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th colspan=2>
<button onclick="openModalFunction('acc_table1')">table one</button>
</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="acc_table2">
<thead><tr><th colspan=2>Table 1</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th colspan=2>
<button onclick="openModalFunction('acc_table2')">table two</button>
</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

<hr>

<button onclick="saveDataToTable()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by considering the **context** in which the button is clicked. We can use [`Node.previousElementSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) or [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to search for the relevant table (depending on the structure of your DOM), in which the new row should be inserted. In that case, you won't need to pass parameters/arguments to the callback, which will require that you keep track of new IDs and etc.

If your `<button>` element is immediately after the `<table>` element, then you can use `e.target.previousElementSibling` to select the `<table>` element of interest, when the click event is fired on the button element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.addAccount').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Table element is immediately before button
    var table = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    
    // Perform sanity check before proceeding
    if (!table || !table.matches('table'))
      return;
    
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_type").value;
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_price").value;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="modal_type" value="MODAL_TYPE" />
<input type="text" id="modal_price" value="MODAL_PRICE" />

<h1>Table 1</h1>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="addAccount">Add account</button>

<h1>Table 2</h1>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="addAccount">Add account</button>

<h1>Table 3</h1>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="addAccount">Add account</button>
```

Alternatively, if your `<button>` element is wrapped in a same parent element (say, a `<div>` element), then you can use a combination of `Element.closest()` and `Element.querySelector()` to find the table in the same parent. Again, no ID is required and all is based on contextual information from DOM hierarchy:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.addAccount').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Table element is immediately before button
    var table = e.target.closest('.wrapper').querySelector('table');

    // Perform sanity check before proceeding
    if (!table)
      return;

    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_type").value;
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_price").value;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="modal_type" value="MODAL_TYPE" />
<input type="text" id="modal_price" value="MODAL_PRICE" />

<hr />

<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="addAccount">Add account</button>
  <p>Random text here</p>
  <h1>Table 1</h1>
  <table>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Table 2</h1>
  <table>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <p>Random text here</p>
  <button type="button" class="addAccount">Add account</button>
</div>
```